# Vagrant can not reach mongod and wants me to install the package 'mongodb-server'

Tags: vagrant, mongodb-.net-driver

while working with vagrant, in course M040,  `mongod -f /shared/rs1_linux.conf` does not work

```
The program 'mongod' is currently not installed. To run 'mongod' please ask your administrator to install the package 'mongodb-server'
```

appears in the command prompt window. I thought it was handled when I had installed vagrant 2.2.2

Comment: Is there anyone overcoming this problem?

Comment: _I thought it had been handled when I ınstalled vagrant 2.2.2_ why would it be done ? have you run any provisioning ? please be precise, you can provide your Vagrantfile and if any provisioning script is run, please provide them as well

Comment: After destroying the vagrant and later again "vagrant up" it worked. Thanks.

Comment: Today I had the same problem. "vagrant provision"  "vagrant destroy" didn't work.

Comment: it would be good you provide more detail - Vagrantfile - any script you use for your provisioning etc

Comment: When I run "vagrant up" command, it say "mongod-m040: Machine already provisioned. Run `vagrant provision` or use the `--provision`
==> mongod-m040: flag to force provisioning. Provisioners marked to run always will still run."

Comment: so I command "vagrant provision"                                                                                   
mongod-m040: Executing: gpg --ignore-time-conflict --no-options --no-default-keyring --homedir /tmp/tmp.7BY2VJcB74 --no-auto-check-trustdb --trust-model always --keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg --primary-keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv 9DA31620334BD75D9DCB49F368818C72E52529D4
    mongod-m040: gpg:
    mongod-m040: requesting key E52529D4 from hkp server keyserver.ubuntu.com

Comment: mongod-m040: ?: keyserver.ubuntu.com: Host not found
    mongod-m040: gpgkeys: HTTP fetch error 7: couldn't connect: Success
    mongod-m040: gpg: no valid OpenPGP data found.
    mongod-m040: gpg: Total number processed: 0
package 'mongodb-server'"       so what should I do?

Comment: The SSH command responded with a non-zero exit status. Vagrant
assumes that this means the command failed. The output for this command
should be in the log above. Please read the output to determine what
went wrong.                                                                                                                Does this mean "Machine has already not provisioned."?

Comment: With "vagrant ssh" I enter VM   "vagrant@m040:~$ mongod --dbpath ~/repl/1 --logpath ~/repl/1/log --port 27017 --replSet M040 --bind_ip_all --fork"                                                                         
I want to set up the replica set                                                                                         Mongo is far away being reachable                                                                   
 "The program 'mongod' is currently not installed. To run 'mongod' please ask your administrator to install  the package 'mongodb-server'